# May I add a word to in some range expression when reading it?

Tags: word-usage

A sentence written as below:

> Expeditions range in length from two weeks to three months, with team of 12-45 people aging 18-70.

Should I add a word to in the range such as 12-45 and 18-70?

That is to say, to read the sentence adding a word to:

> Expeditions range in length from two weeks to three months, with team of twelve to forty-five people aging eighteen to seventy.

or read it without adding word:

> Expeditions range in length from two weeks to three months, with team of twelve  forty-five people aging eighteen  seventy.

Comment: You need 'to', and cannot omit it.

Comment: "each with a team" or just "with teams", but not "with team". "aged 18 to 70" or "aged 18-70".

Comment: Also, not "aging" [or even correctly spelled "ageing"]. It's "aged".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *12-45* would be spoken as *twelve to forty-five.* otherwise, the figures would sound like times of day or dates! As others have commented, your sentence should read *with teams of 12-45 people aged 18-70.*